# Unable to build any apk

Tags: unity-game-engine

I can't build another APK in Unity. Always the same error.
SO : Win 10 64 bits
Unity version : 2018.3.9f1 with Android Building Tools

I create empty project with only button and i try to export apk to try but
I get this error >>>

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_251\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.6.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

    stderr[

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Failed to capture snapshot of output files for task ':mergeReleaseAssets' property 'outputDir' during up-to-date check.
    > Failed to create MD5 hash for file 'D:\Unity\TEST Game\test project\Temp\gradleOut\build\intermediates\merged_assets\release\mergeReleaseAssets\out\bin\Data\Managed\etc\mono\2.0\DefaultWsdlHelpGenerator.aspx' as it does not exist.

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

    BUILD FAILED in 24s
    ]
    stdout[
    :checkReleaseClasspath UP-TO-DATE
    :preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
    :compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
    :checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
    :generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
    :prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
    :mainApkListPersistenceRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
    :generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    :mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    :createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
    :processReleaseManifest
    :splitsDiscoveryTaskRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :processReleaseResources
    :generateReleaseSources
    :javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
    :compileReleaseNdk NO-SOURCE
    :compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
    :lintVitalRelease
    :mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
    :compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
    :generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :mergeReleaseAssets FAILED
    19 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 15 up-to-date
    ]
    exit code: 1
    UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <df7ba4d130594d168eec372b930522d4>:0)
    UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <df7ba4d130594d168eec372b930522d4>:0)
    UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <df7ba4d130594d168eec372b930522d4>:0)
    UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <df7ba4d130594d168eec372b930522d4>:0)
    UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <df7ba4d130594d168eec372b930522d4>:0)
    Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
    UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <df7ba4d130594d168eec372b930522d4>:0)
    UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <df7ba4d130594d168eec372b930522d4>:0)
    UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <df7ba4d130594d168eec372b930522d4>:0)
    UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

My settings and things I've tried:

- JDK version 1.8
- SDK build tool version 25
- Swap from Gradle build to internal build (as internal build a different error comes up)
- Reinstall all and restart my computer and the problem still occurs

Comment: Weird error, but can you try this weird idea? create a new project on a folder location that does not contain spaces. I mean, instead of "TEST Game/test project" use something like 'TestGame' and 'TestProject'.... The error is about not finding `DefaultWsdlHelpGenerator.aspx` which seems not unique of Unity

Comment: Thank you very much brother your weird idea it's working when i change it without space it's exported without any problem.

Comment: Awesome! I will post that as an answer. It could be useful for someone else!

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable usb debugging in your phone programmer options

Comment: Hy brother Bartek i didn't export to phone i export file apk to the computer.

Comment: i already update java and jdk jre sdk ndk also uninstall unity and install again but nothing changed.

Comment: Well then i have no clues sorry

Comment: Thank you brother no problem <3

Answer (score 0):

It is a weird error, it seems like is not related to Unity specifically.

The process is not being able to find this file `DefaultWsdlHelpGenerator`.

```
...'D:\Unity\TEST Game\test project\Temp\gradleOut\build\...\etc\mono\2.0\DefaultWsdlHelpGenerator.aspx' as it does not exist.
```

File situated inside your project's folder, `D:\Unity\TEST Game\test project`

As a not friend of spaces on paths, I suggested you try with another project without spaces on the path, and according to your comment that worked!

ps;
As this could be helpful for someone else, I write this as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

This error is related to the Unity Project Settings -> Editor -> Unity Remote -> Device -> any Android device. Just set to "none", and the error is gone.